# How to update the parent/child of all rows in the tree (ltree)?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, update

Here are my configurations:
DB type: `postgresql` (9.3 if that's necessary)
Table name: `product_sections`
Column names: `section_id (integer)` & `section_path (ltree)`

### [image: table_image]

**Detail:**
I have one reference value: `section_id: 15` & `section_path: Automation_Solutionz`. So, when I want to rename `Automation_Solutionz` to, say `Chrome`, I want all references of `Automation_Solutionz` to be updated.

*FROM:*

```
Automation_Solutionz
Automation_Solutionz.Test_Case_Creation
Automation_Solutionz.Test_Case_Creation.Automation
Automation_Solutionz.Test_Case_Creation.Manual
```

*TO:*

```
Chrome
Chrome.Test_Case_Creation
Chrome.Test_Case_Creation.Automation
Chrome.Test_Case_Creation.Manual
```

---

Similarly, when I update a value which is in the middle, it should rename those too. In the case above, `Test_Case_Creation` should be renamed to something like `TestCase` or anything else. The same goes for any item which is either in the middle, end or at the start.

Hope, I explained things correctly. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does anything prevent you from casting your values to `text`, do a replace and then cast back to `ltree`?  Like `SELECT replace('a.b.c'::ltree::text, 'b', 'd')::ltree;`

Comment: no, I'm free to use text too!

Comment: But, there's a catch. Say, some row has this value: `Test_Case_Create.Case`. When you replace `Case` with something else, the row will have the value: `Test_X_Create.X` which is not what I want. I want it to become `Test_Case_Create.X`

Comment: In an `x.y.x.z` ltree it does not make much sense to replace both `x`. Typically you'd want to replace a subpath anchored at left by another subpath, for example `x.y.x.*` by `x.y.t.*` (as opposed to `x` by `t`)

Comment: Well it's not a `x.y.x.z` tree. Its just that, one label i.e `x` maybe inside of the word (or more specifically a label) `y`

Answer (score 2):

One can view the `ltree` data type as a simple `text` with some constraints.  The most important of these constraints is that a label is bordered by dots if part of a *label path*.  Obviously, if it stands at either end, one dot will be missing; when alone, the dots are completely missing.

Fortunately, casting between the two types is easy.  This way we can set up a small set of rules for handling replacement, using [`lquery`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ltree.html) to find the cases:

```
-- 1. replace when the label is the whole labelpath
replace(section_path::text, 'to_be_replaced', 'replacement') 
    WHERE section_path ~ 'to_be_replaced'::lquery

-- 2. replace when the label is at the end
replace(section_path::text, '.to_be_replaced', '.replacement')
    WHERE section_path ~ '*.to_be_replaced'::lquery

-- 3. replace when the label is at the beginning
replace(section_path::text, 'to_be_replaced.', '.replacement')
    WHERE section_path ~ 'to_be_replaced.*'::lquery

-- 4. replace when the label is in the middle
replace(section_path::text, '.to_be_replaced.', '.replacement.')
    WHERE section_path ~ '*.to_be_replaced.*'::lquery
```

In cases 2-4, mind the dots in the search and replacement values of `replace()`.  This way you can be sure you always replace the whole label, not just parts of it.

Comment: Hey thanks for such detailed answer. I'll let you know if I was successful and have your answer as accepted. BTW, can you tell me what lquery is?  And what does ~ operator exactly do? Thanks again :)

Comment: I cannot, but the docs can ;) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ltree.html

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to achieve this ....

If the replaced text is only one level tree

```
update product_sections 
set section_path = 'Chrome' 
where section_path = 'Automation_Solutionz'
```

If the replaced text is at the beginning

```
update product_sections 
set section_path = 'Chrome' || subpath(section_path,1) 
where section_path ~ 'Automation_Solutionz.*'
```

If the replaced text is in the middle

```
update product_sections 
set section_path = subpath(section_path, 0, index(section_path, 'Test_Case_Creation')) || 
                   'Testcase' || 
                   subpath(section_path, index(section_path, 'Test_Case_Creation') + 1) 
where section_path ~ '*.Test_Case_Creation.*{1,}';
```

If the replaced text is at the end

```
update product_sections 
set section_path = subpath(section_path, 0, index(section_path, 'Test_Case_Creation')) || 
                   'Testcase' 
where section_path ~ '*.Test_Case_Creation.*{0}';
```

Comment: Yes, this is a nice solution with `ltree`-only functionality.  Mine is a bit less advanced but more readable :)