# how to update new parent node in the middle of the postgresql ltree by some simple update SQL statement?

Tags: postgresql

I follow this URL to make some SOP for my colleague.
[How to update the parent/child of all rows in the tree (ltree)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90797/how-to-update-the-parent-child-of-all-rows-in-the-tree-ltree)

However, my colleague hope to use some simple statement about "UPDATE" for adding or deleting some parent nodes without complex Regular Expression statements.

Is there any better statement by using UPDATE? Thanks for advance.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://gbif.blogspot.ie/2012/06/taxonomic-trees-in-postgresql.html).

Comment: thanks a lot. But the author offer a solution about changing top node or lowest node, what I need is change the node in the middle.

Comment: I believe my answer on the linked question specifies whether a node is in the middle, see case 4.

Answer (score 0):

I just try another stupid solution:

```
update product_sections 
  set section_path = text2ltree('Automation_Solutionz.Test_Case_Execution.treetype') ||
                     subltree(section_path,1,nlevel(section_path)-1) 
where section_path ~ 'Automation_Solutionz.Test_Case_Execution.*'::lquery
```